# is $f(0)$ undefine or $f(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

let $$f(x)=\int_{-x}^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$$

A function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has removable discontinuous at $x=0$ with
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

So, Can I say $f(0)=0$?
or $f(0)$ is just undefined because $x=0$ is not in a domain of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

---

ex2) Let $$g(x)=\int_{-x}^x\ln tdt$$
Then Can I say $g(0)=0$?

I'm so confused. Need help

Comment: The function $f$ is defined at zero---the integral over a single point is zero.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes I know but I wanna know it still works on out of domain of integrand.

Comment: @bFur4list when saying what a function is, *you* decide where it is defined. I could define $h(x) = x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, so $h$ would not be defined at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(0)=0$, by the definiton of the "empty" Riemann integral.

Comment: It still works on out of domain of integrand?

Comment: @bFur4list Yes, the value of the integrand at a single point doesn't affect the integral, so it doesn't matter how it's defined there.

Comment: @bFur4list Well, for a "casual" Riemann integral, we would need the integrand to be defined on the whole domain. In our case, $x \mapsto \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is not defined at $0$, but we usually extend it to $0$ as well, because it's a removable singularity, as you noted it. So it's up to you: do you define $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ at $0$? What does $\int$ mean for you, i.e. how do you define the integral of a function?

Comment: As @saulspatz mentioned it, it does not matter if you define it as $1$ or as $42$ at $0$, it won't change the value of the integral. Because of this, we can easily extend the definition of the integral to cover the case when some points are missing from the domain.

Comment: @bFur4list About your second example: $x \mapsto \log(x)$ is not defined at non-positive values, so you can't really integrate it from $-x$ to $x$. Of course, you can say that the integral is zero from $0$ to $0$, but does that mean anything in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$F(0)=\int _0^0 f(t) dt$$ where $$f(t)=\frac {\sin t }{t}$$

You may define $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\ne 0$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x=0$
 Then you have $$\int _0^0 f(t) dt =\int _0^0 g(t) dt = 0$$